# Receiving ORA-01843: not a valid month error while retrieving data between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in oracle database table which is `Varchar2`. In this column I am storing date line 29-1-2021 or 28-12-2020. I want to retrieve data from below query between two dates then I am getting error of Invalid month. How can I resolve this issue ?

```
SELECT Line_Stop_Id, Function_name, Product_family, line_description, Reason_Category, Reason_detail, 
  Product_item, product_description, request_raised_date, request_raised_time, cm.EMP_NAME as raised_by, Lse.User_Closer_Description,
  Cm1.Emp_Name as Closer_User, Lse.User_Closer_Date, Lse.Final_Closer_Description, Lse.Final_Closer_Date, Lse.Final_Closer_Time,
  Cm2.Emp_Name as Final_Closer, Lse.Resource_Effected ,
  ROUND(24*(sysdate - to_date(Request_Raised_Date
  ||' '
  ||request_raised_time, 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'))) AS TAT
  FROM Xx_Lsp_Linestoppage_Entry lse 
  Left join Emp_Master cm ON Lse.Raised_By = Cm.Emp_No
  Left join Emp_Master cm1 ON Lse.Closer_User = Cm1.Emp_No
  Left join Emp_Master cm2 ON Lse.Final_Closed_By = Cm2.Emp_No
  where TO_DATE(Lse.Request_Raised_Date, 'DD-Mon-RR') Between TO_DATE('01-Jan-21', 'DD-Mon-RR') and TO_DATE('29-Jan-21', 'DD-Mon-RR');
```

Comment: Why are you storing date values as varchar? That's a really, really bad idea. Every time you do that, a unicorn dies. And the problem you have is a direct result of that wrong decision (I bet someone said "yes we can validate all dates before storing them in that horrible format. Trust me, there won't be a problem")

Comment: _Never_ store dates as text, always use a proper date column.

Comment: I don't understand. You write that column `Request_Raised_Date` in table `Xx_Lsp_Linestoppage_Entry` contains a string that represents a date, e.g. _29-1-2021_ yet in your [SQL] query criteria you are using a different format string, namely `DD-Mon-RR`. Are you familiar with Oracle's [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)?

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question and post the entire [Oracle] error message you are getting.

Comment: Unbelievable, some people still use 2-digits for year - or should I say "some people *again* use 2-digits"? Maybe the [Y2K-Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) is too long ago meanwhile and people are not aware of it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the validity of your date values stored as strings before a conversion and do a cleanup of them (of fix them).

This can be done via, for example, cursor in PL/SQL block (or wrapped in function to export query results or filter by its value):

```
declare
  l_date date;
begin

  for r in (
    select distinct
      request_raised_time
    from Xx_Lsp_Linestoppage_Entry
    /*To reduce rows in cursor*/
    where not regexp_like('^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}')
  ) loop
  
    begin
      
      l_date := to_date(r.q, 'dd-mm-yyyy');
    exception
      when others then dbms_output.put_line('Invalid date: ' || r.q);
    end;
  
  end loop;
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6079bb451b73b36b8242adf45cc408a3)*

**Note**, that you need to quote dashes inside format to make it exact, because Oracle treats unquoted dash as any symbol from quite wide set of delimiters. So it will process `01/12/2020` as `date '2020-12-01'`, not as invalid date.

```
select to_date('01/12/2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') as dt from dual;

DT                   
-------------------- 
2021-12-01T00:00:00Z 


Elapsed: 00:00:00.002
1 rows selected.

select to_date('01-12-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') as dt from dual;

DT                   
-------------------- 
2021-12-01T00:00:00Z 


Elapsed: 00:00:00.002
1 rows selected.

select to_date('01$12$2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') as dt from dual;

DT                   
-------------------- 
2021-12-01T00:00:00Z 


Elapsed: 00:00:00.002
1 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the date in the format `29-1-2020 (dd-mm-yyyy)` so use this format in the to_Date

replace

```
DD-Mon-RR
```

with

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

Comment: Thanks @Popeye for your response. Still receiving same error

Comment: where TO_DATE(Lse.Request_Raised_Date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') Between TO_DATE('01-01-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') and TO_DATE('29-01-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy');

Comment: Change the format, here also `DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'`

Comment: @MoinKhan do the values in column `Request_Raised_Date` contain leading spaces or trailing spaces or embedded spaces? For example: `29 - 01 - 2021`

Answer (score 0):

Probably being the Lse.Request_Raised_Date field of type varchar2 it contains more information than you need for your query.
I think the best way is to select a string that only identifies the part necessary for the identification of the date using the function:

```
 substr(string , string start from , string lenght )
```

This is an example:

```
 select to_date(substr('29-01-2021 23:01:55',1,10),'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;

 TO_DATE (SU
 ----------
 29-01-2021
```

instead of my string '29 -01-2021 23:01:55 ' enter field Lse.Request_Raised_Date

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on conversion error`:

```
to_date(Request_Raised_Date || ' ' || request_raised_time 
        default null on conversion error, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

This returns `NULL` instead of an error.

Hopefully, this is a lesson on why you should not store date/time values as strings.  You can actually look for the bad values using:

```
select Request_Raised_Date, request_raised_time
from Xx_Lsp_Linestoppage_Entry
where to_date(Request_Raised_Date || ' ' || request_raised_time 
            default null on conversion error, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') is null and
      Request_Raised_Date is not null
```

This may give you some ideas on how to fix the data.